# How to force pandas read_csv to use float32 for all float columns?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Because

- I don't need double precision
- My machine has limited memory and I want to process bigger datasets
- I need to pass the extracted data (as matrix) to BLAS libraries, and BLAS calls for single precision are 2x faster than for double precision equivalence.

Note that not all columns in the raw csv file have float types. I only need to set float32 as the default for float columns.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample 100 rows of data to determine dtypes.
df_test = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=100)

float_cols = [c for c in df_test if df_test[c].dtype == "float64"]
float32_cols = {c: np.float32 for c in float_cols}

df = pd.read_csv(filename, engine='c', dtype=float32_cols)
```

This first reads a sample of 100 rows of data (modify as required) to determine the type of each column.

It the creates a list of those columns which are 'float64', and then uses dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary with these columns as the keys and 'np.float32' as the value for each key.

Finally, it reads the whole file using the 'c' engine (required for assigning dtypes to columns) and then passes the float32_cols dictionary as a parameter to dtype.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=100)
>>> df
   int_col  float1 string_col  float2
0        1     1.2          a     2.2
1        2     1.3          b     3.3
2        3     1.4          c     4.4

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
int_col       3 non-null int64
float1        3 non-null float64
string_col    3 non-null object
float2        3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(1)

df32 = pd.read_csv(filename, engine='c', dtype={c: np.float32 for c in float_cols})
>>> df32.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
int_col       3 non-null int64
float1        3 non-null float32
string_col    3 non-null object
float2        3 non-null float32
dtypes: float32(2), int64(1), object(1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution which does not depend on `.join` or does not require reading the file twice:

```
float64_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='float64').columns
mapper = {col_name: np.float32 for col_name in float64_cols}
df = df.astype(mapper)
```

Or for kicks as a one-liner:

```
df = df.astype({c: np.float32 for c in df.select_dtypes(include='float64').columns})
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander's is a great answer. Some columns may need to be precise. If so, you may need to stick more conditionals into your list comprehension to exclude some columns the `any` or `all` built ins are handy:

```py
float_cols = [c for c in df_test if all([df_test[c].dtype == "float64", 
             not df_test[c].name == 'Latitude', not df_test[c].name =='Longitude'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about column order, there's also [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) which avoids having to `read_csv` twice:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df_float = df.select_dtypes(include=float).astype("float32")
df_not_float = df.select_dtypes(exclude=float)

df = df_float.join(df_not_float)
```

Or, if you want to convert *all* non-string columns (e.g. integer columns) to float:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df_not_str = df.select_dtypes(exclude=object).astype("float32")
df_str = df.select_dtypes(include=object)

df = df_not_str.join(df_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's slightly more efficient to call the dtypes, as opposed to jorijnsmit's solution...

jorijnsmit's:

```
%%timeit
df.astype({c: 'float32' for c in df.select_dtypes(include='float64').columns})
754 µs ± 6.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

calling dtypes:

```
%%timeit
df.astype({c: 'float32' for c in df.dtypes.index[df.dtypes == 'float64']})
538 µs ± 343 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```